# WordPress wont load 2 CSS Files(can only load one)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

i have a Issue, that my WordPress Site will only load 1 CSS File.
I have 2 CSS Files:
- My own Stylesheet
- and the Bootstrap CSS File

I do import my JS File to, but this doesnt matter here, or does it?
I have the following Code in my `header.php` File:

```
wp_register_style("style", get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css", '', '1.0.0');
wp_enqueue_style('style');

wp_register_style("bootstrap.min", get_template_directory_uri() . "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", '', '1.0.0');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap.min');
```

With this Code, only my Bootstrap File gets loaded, but when i change my Code to the Following(Comment the Bootstrap import):

```
wp_register_style("style", get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css", '', '1.0.0');
wp_enqueue_style('style');

//wp_register_style("bootstrap.min", get_template_directory_uri() . "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", '', '1.0.0');
//wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap.min');
```

my own Stylesheet is loading correctly, but the Bootstrap is not loading(cause its "commented" is this the right way to say in English?).

How can i load all 2 CSS Files correctly?

Comment: Just as an FYI.  You don't need to register the style.  You can just use ```wp_enqueue_style()``` with your params and it will both register and enqueue with one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code in your functions.php and check

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
wp_register_style("style", get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css", '', '1.0.0');
wp_enqueue_style('style');

wp_register_style("bootstrap-min", get_template_directory_uri() . "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", '', '1.0.0');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-min');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```